# How to add image to hugo with local and remote

Tags: hugo

I want add an image to hugo's md file. And I want see it on local and website, and use a single directory to store it. So I try to put it on `/content/posts/image/xxx.img` and write md file with `![](/content/posts/images/2022-11-10-17-33-49.png)` it's work in vscode  but not in website. Is there way to get it?

Comment: How are you deploying the website? Have you uploaded the image, as well? When you say it works in VSCode, do you mean in the Markdown preview?

Answer (score 0):

Find it in hugo https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-add-image-to-hugo-with-local-and-remote/41391/8

The answer is change the conf file.

```ini
[[module.mounts]]
source = 'static'
target = 'static'

[[module.mounts]]
source = 'images'
target = 'static/images'
```